# Why green on green bar paper?

Tags: usability, color

One of the biggest business application my company builds uses green and white as the alternating background color in tables. This is due to the green bar paper used in former decades with line printers. I was wondering why they chose green.

Wikipedia only states that it was used to help the reader stay in one line, however this is, in my opinion, a consequence of the alternating background and not specially due to the green color.

Does anybody know why they particularly chose green and not any other color? Is that due to any ergonomic/usability reason?

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally bankers had green lampshades and green visors as well, I believe it had something to do with early incandescent lights. Maybe green books helped too?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're reading too much into it. The three colors I've seen most often are light green, light blue and light gray. My SalesForce application, for instance, uses light gray; my company's internal apps, which I worked on, are all light blue.

All colors are used - I've even seen light yellow and light orange. I didn't find them to be pleasant to look at, but that's me.